# Heroku node deployment doesn't respect file name changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I changed the filename of one of my routes from authroutes to authRoutes. When I commit the changes and deploy to heroku, the build fails because it is still looking for authroutes.

```
2017-09-16T15:57:57.744695+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './routes/authRoutes.js'
```

The only reference to the file is in my index.js file via:

```
require('./routes/authRoutes.js')(app);
```

I make the change in the index.js file when committing. I've tried clearing my build cache with the heroku-repo plugin as well as making changes to the file itself. If I switch the file name back as well as the reference in index.js, everything works without a hitch. I've tried manually changing the file with heroku bash but it just switches back after the build process is completed to the all lowercase version.

Thanks!

Comment: strange that cach/repo flush did not work and that a build would not see new Hash values of files whose content changes.  so try change to fileName of the router in ur app.or drop / add the entire file containing the router to accomplish a real cache/push FORCE

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure I understood that. You mean to bring the route into the index.js and not separate it at all? Then maybe put it back with the correct file name in a separate commit? I might try just spinning up a whole new heroku dyno.

Comment: by "drop / add" ... rm the file with your router... do a push... add back the previously rm'd router file... do another push

Comment: Dropping and adding the router file on two separate commits solved my issue. You should submit it as an answer rather than a comment!

Answer (score 1):

The buildpack may be doing something with the hash comparison against the repo that requires a change bigger or more significant than a single byte changing Case.

If that is so, why dont you try a drop/add of an entire file across 2 successive git push actions?

1. rm your router file from project
2. git push heroku master ( node start may fail but so what )
3. add back your "new" router file with the change that the repo hash failed to recognize

   4. git push heroku master  with the new version of the router

that should fool the buildpack hasher for node projects enough to FORCE thru your change.

Comment: Removing the file all together did, in fact, force the change I needed. The subsequent commit where I added it back in with the correct file name did the trick.